# Why won't my webform send data to my email?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to coding and Im trying to find out why my php code will not send my form data to my email if someone could direct me to somewhere Where i could learn how to get it to send or give me some tips I would really appreciate it.

HTML: [UPDATED]

```
<a id="faq-scroll"></a>
    <section id="faq">
            <div class="row pad-large">
<div class="row">
            <div class="large-8 large-centered columns pad-bottom-small">
                <div id="faq-form" class="text-center">
                    <form method = "POST" action = "mail.php">
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" />
                        <input id="middleinitial" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" name="middleinitial" />
                        <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" />
                        <input id="email2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" name="email2" />
                        <select id="form_dob_month" name="dob_month">
                        <option value="-">Date</option>
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">Febuary</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
                        <select id="form_dob_day" type="radio" name="dob_day">
                        <option value="-">Of</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
                        <select id="form_dob_year" type="radio" name="dob_year">
                        <option value="-">Birth</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="2007">2007</option>
                        <option value="2006">2006</option>
                        <option value="2005">2005</option>
                        <option value="2004">2004</option>
                        <option value="2003">2003</option>
                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                        <option value="2001">2001</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                        <option value="1959">1959</option>
                        <option value="1958">1958</option>
                        <option value="1957">1957</option>
                        <option value="1956">1956</option>
                        <option value="1955">1955</option>
                        <option value="1954">1954</option>
                        <option value="1953">1953</option>
                        <option value="1952">1952</option>
                        <option value="1951">1951</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="1949">1949</option>
                        <option value="1948">1948</option>
                        <option value="1947">1947</option>
                        <option value="1946">1946</option>
                        <option value="1945">1945</option>
                        <option value="1944">1944</option>
                        <option value="1943">1943</option>
                        <option value="1942">1942</option>
                        <option value="1941">1941</option>
                        <option value="1940">1940</option>
                        <option value="1939">1939</option>
                        <option value="1938">1938</option>
                        <option value="1937">1937</option>
                        <option value="1936">1936</option>
                        <option value="1935">1935</option>
                        <option value="1934">1934</option>
                        <option value="1933">1933</option>
                        <option value="1932">1932</option>
                        <option value="1931">1931</option>
                        <option value="1930">1930</option>
                        <option value="1929">1929</option>
                        <option value="1928">1928</option>
                        <option value="1927">1927</option>
                        <option value="1926">1926</option>
                        <option value="1925">1925</option>
                        <option value="1924">1924</option>
                        <option value="1923">1923</option>
                        <option value="1922">1922</option>
                        <option value="1921">1921</option>
                        <option value="1920">1920</option>
                        <option value="1919">1919</option>
                        <option value="1918">1918</option>
                        <option value="1917">1917</option>
                        <option value="1916">1916</option>
                        <option value="1915">1915</option>
                        <option value="1914">1914</option>
                        <option value="1913">1913</option>
                        <option value="1912">1912</option>
                        <option value="1911">1911</option>
                        <option value="1910">1910</option>
        </select>               
                        <input id="social" type="text" placeholder="Social Security #" name="socialsecurity#" />
                        <input id="Driver" type="text" placeholder="Driver License #" name="driverlicense#" />
                        <input id="cellphone" type="text" placeholder="Cell Phone" name="cellphone" />
                        <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" name="streetaddress" />
                        <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zipcode" />
                        <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" />
                        <select id="form_state" type="radio" name="State">
                        <option value="-">State</option>
                        <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="5">California</option>
                        <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="9">Florida</option>
                        <option value="10">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="12">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="13">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="14">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="15">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="16">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="19">Maine</option>
                        <option value="20">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="22">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="23">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="24">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="25">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="26">Montana</option>
                        <option value="27">Nebraska </option>
                        <option value="28">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="30">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="31">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="32">New York</option>
                        <option value="33">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="34">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="35">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="37">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="39">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="40">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="41">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="42">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="43">Texas</option>
                        <option value="44">Utah</option>
                        <option value="45">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="46">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="47">Washington</option>
                        <option value="48">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="50">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>   
                        <input id="timeataddress" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Address" name="timeatpresentaddress" />
                        <input id="rent" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Rent/Mortgage Payment" name="monthlyrent/mortgagepayment" />
                        <input id="jobtitle" type="text" placeholder="Present Job Title" name="presentjobtitle" />
                        <input id="employer" type="text" placeholder="Present Employer" name="presentemployer" />
                        <input id="employerphone" type="text" placeholder="Employer Phone Number" name="employerphonenumber" />
                        <input id="jobtime" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Job" name="timeatpresentjob" />
                        <input id="grossincome" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Gross Income" name="monthlygrossincome" />
                        <input id="question-ask" type="submit" value="SUBMIT YOUR APPLICATION" class="btn btn-green" />
                        <div id="details-error"><i class="icon-alert">&nbsp;</i>Please enter all details correctly</div>
                        <div id="form-sent"><i class="icon-check">&nbsp;</i>Message sent, thanks for your enquiry</div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $body = $_POST['emailaddress'] . ' has submitted some data'
        'First Name: ' . $_POST['firstname']
        'Middle Name: ' . $_POST['middleinitial'] 
        'Last Name: ' . $_POST['lastname']
        'email2: '  = $_POST['emailaddress']
        'form_dob_month: '  = $_POST['dob_month']
        'form_dob_day: '  = $_POST['dob_day']
        'form_dob_year: '  = $_POST['dob_year']
        'social: '  = $_POST['socialsecurity#']
        'Driver: '  = $_POST['driverlicense#']
        'cellphone: '  = $_POST['cellphone']
        'address: '  = $_POST['streetaddress']
        'zip: '  = $_POST['zipcode']
        'city: '  = $_POST['city']
        'form_state: '  = $_POST['state']
        'timeataddress: '  = $_POST['timeatpresentaddress']
        'rent: '  = $_POST['monthlyrent/mortgagepayment']
        'jobtitle: '  = $_POST['presentjobtitle']
        'employer: '  = $_POST['presentemployer']
        'employerphone: '  = $_POST['employerphonenumber']
        'jobtime: '  = $_POST['timeatpresentjob']
        'grossincome: '  = $_POST['monthlygrossincome']

    mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body);
 }
```

Comment: have you done `print_r($_POST)` ? what is the output?

Comment: You're moving your posted data into local variables but I don't see where you actually include them in your email. `$body` only contains the sender's email address and your short note string

Comment: you should remove your emailadress from your code example - you might receive spam

Comment: *"Im trying to find out why my php code will not send my form data to my email"* ... because you're not telling it to?

Comment: Please I'm new to coding so if you guys could explain a little more as I am confused on where my output should go..  and what about the $body? @Machavity

Comment: @baig772 I thought mail("iamdrivingtodayleads@yahoo.com", was my output?

Comment: @CD001 I am telling it to send to my email though mail("iamdrivingtodayleads@yahoo.com,

Comment: You're not actually sending the form data anywhere ... you'd need to append it to `$body` (after error trapping, formatting etc) in some way for it to be included in the email; which is what @Machavity was saying.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have the data sent to you, you have to have the data included in the email. Your PHP script is only saying this

```
$email2  = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$body = $email2.' has submitted some data';
mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body);
```

The rest of the lines are irrelevant because they don't interact with `mail()` or `$body`. To make them relevant you need to append them to `$body`

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $body = $_POST['emailaddress'] . ' has submitted some data' . "\n" .
        'First Name: ' . $_POST['firstname'] . "\n" . 
        'Middle Name: ' . $_POST['middleinitial'] . "\n" . 
        'Last Name: ' . $_POST['lastname'] . "\n";
    //You get the idea so you can write the rest

    mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body);
 }
```

Comment: I updated my php code does it look correct machavity?

Comment: Did you try running it first? The parser will throw an error if you do. And you need to look at what you did vs what I did. Does it look the same to you?

Comment: I did try running it first and it still won't send @Machavity

Comment: You're not concatenating the string right http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: could you please give me an example on how to string it correctly @Machavity I would greatly appreciate it, or maybe point me to a tutorial video I have looked at the link and I am new to php so its kind of all a foreign language to me thank you..

Comment: @FamoJoe I did. Read my answer again. Everything you need is there